# Orthogonal check; incorrect maths or function usage?

Tags: math, scipy

I am comparing 2 angles (in degrees) and I want to know if they are orthogonal.

So I use the following `scipy.spatial.distance` function:

```
print( dist.cosine([181], [1]) )
```

However it prints out `0.0`. Shouldn't this result give me either `1` or `-1`? Ie, its in the opposite direction? Am I using the function wrong?

Comment: Often, reading the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cosine) of the function you are trying to use is helpful.

Comment: Two angles specified in degrees are orthogonal if their difference is 90, modulo 180, aren't they? I'm thinking maybe the calculation is just some arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

`dist.cosine` [actually computes the **cosine distance**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cosine), which (wikipedia) is a term that

> is often used for the complement in positive space, that is:
>
> D <sub>C</sub> ( A , B ) = 1 − S <sub>C</sub> ( A , B )
>
> where D <sub>C</sub> is the cosine distance and S <sub>C</sub> is the
>   cosine similarity.

This isn't what you want at all. I'm no Python expert, but doesn't

```
math.cos(math.radians(181 - 1))
```

do what you want?